# ActiveRecord requires ruby version >= 2.2.2

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rake

I need activerecord for rake, but when i try to install it it says:

```
activesupport-5.0.0.1 requires ruby version >= 2.2.2,
which is incompatible with the current version, ruby 1.9.3p484
```

I tried changing ruby with rbenv to 2.2.2

```
rbenv versions
```

**outputs**

> system
>       * 2.2.2 (set by /home/user/.rbenv/version)
>         2.3.1

But when i go ruby -v it says

> ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]

Also tried removing it but when i install rake

```
sudo apt-get install rake
```

and I get this **output**

> The following extra packages will be installed:
>
> libruby1.9.1 ruby ruby1.9.1

But, I need ruby version 2.2.2 or later to be active (ruby -v) to install active record so i can do the rake command.

Comment: Did you run `rbenv global 2.2.2`?

Comment: Yes i did, and there is a * at rbenv version for that, but it still looks like 1.9.3p484 is active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had help with this one and resolved it. In my case i changed gemfile.lock from

```
    GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    activemodel (5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
    activerecord (5.0.0.1)
      activemodel (= 5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
      arel (~> 7.0)
    activesupport (5.0.0.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (7.1.4)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    minitest (5.9.1)
    mysql2 (0.4.5)
    rake (11.3.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activerecord
  mysql2
  rake

BUNDLED WITH
   1.13.6
```

to this one (most important is activerecord version):

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    activemodel (3.1.3)
      activesupport (= 3.1.3)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
    activerecord (3.1.3)
      activemodel (= 3.1.3)
      activesupport (= 3.1.3)
      arel (~> 2.2.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activesupport (3.1.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (2.2.1)
    builder (3.0.0)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    multi_json (1.0.4)
    mysql2 (0.3.11)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    tzinfo (0.3.31)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activerecord
  mysql2
  rake

BUNDLED WITH
   1.13.6
```

And then installed activerecord and all other that i needed

```
gem install activerecord -v 3.1.3
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter
gem uninstall mysql2
gem install mysql -v 0.3.11
```

And the rake worked.

```
 rake db:migrate[]
```

Hope this will help someone! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are messing things up.

```
sudo apt-get install rake
```

is a *system wide* debian package, that knows nothing about `rbenv`. Remove it as well as you have system ruby removed.

Afterwards, do:

```
rbenv global 2.2.2
gem install rake # ⇐ THIS
```